# Pageviews for iFrame content not matching pageviews for parent page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, iframe, page-views

I have a page with content hosted in an iFrame, both using the same Google Analytics account ID. When I look at the pages report, the parent page has about 9000 unique views, but the iFrame content only has 3700. Anyone have an idea what could cause that kind of discrepancy?

My only guess is that it would be caused by people moving on before the iFrame content has a chance to load, but the average time on page for the host page is 56 seconds, so that doesn't seem possible.

[This](http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_le-creuset-lid_10151_-1_20002) is the page in question.

The flipbook is hosted in the iFrame on a separate domain. I have each page of the flipbook triggering a virtual pageview to try to evaluate engagement with the book - when the flipbook loads, it fires a pageview for the page it is on, so that is the page I'm using for the 3700 number. I also looked at the source of the iFrame in the pages report, and that number just about matches the virtual pageviews so that piece is consistent.

Comment: I've looked at this using HTTPFox and wanted to know what virtual page you are looking at that is giving you 3700? Is it /MarinerStar/View/Page3?

Comment: /MarinerStar/View/Page1 has 3,573 unique views for October, and that's the pageview that fires automatically when the parent page loads. The parent page has 9,393 unique views for October, so I would think the Page1 views would match...

Comment: Have you tried creating a profile (view) specific to your IP? Have you monitored the real-time content report when you visit the page?  What do the other virtual page #'s look like for the flipbook? /Page2, /Page3, etc?

Comment: Do a breakdown by browsers, if the iframe does not show older IE versions you are possibly missing a valid p3p policy.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, good idea, but it shows all the same browser versions so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Blexy, I hadn't looked at the real-time report previously and each time I check, no one is looking at the page at the moment. We're not promoting it as heavily.  The other virtual page #'s show a drop as the flipbook goes on, which I would expect.  Page2 has 3,575 views (which is weird, it should match page1 since they load at the same time, but whatever).

Comment: When I look at the flipbook url (http://lcoawebservices.com/mariner/101513_Mariner-Launch.html) with the GA debugger it shows three trackPageview Calls, two of them with virtuarl Urls. Maybe it the iframe that is overcounting and you mistake the virtual urls as coming from the parent page (sorry, just guessing).

Comment: @surfbird0713 Are you still seeing a difference in Pageviews? I have some ideas as to why this might be the case.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be using `_getLinkerUrl()`.  That would be my best guess as to the source of the problem.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory

Elsewhere, I found this comment:

> If you don't use _getLinkerUrl GA inside the iframe will think it's 
>   a brand new visit referral from the top level page.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724605/google-analytics-and-iframe-content-will-all-tracking-work

If you say page 2 and 3 are also counted on page-load, then if these are both triggering a top level page visit at the same time, then it would explain why your top page has three times as many hits.